# Overwritting class patametres Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, python-class

I want to create class where user declare some attributes and other attributes are calculated on the basis of previously declared parametres.

```
class Sum:
def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.result = None

@property 
def result(self):
    if self.result is None:
        self.result = self.a + self.b
    return self.result
```

When I declare a and b, result is still None. How can I solve this to calculate result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you have declared `member` and `property` both at the same time
Either of them will work.
In your case, if you want the previous results use this code

```
class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.output = None

    @property
    def result(self):
        if self.output is None:
            self.output = self.a + self.b
        return self.output


sum = Sum(1, 2)
print(sum.result)
sum.a = 3
print(sum.result)
```

will print

```
3
3
```

Or if you don't want the previous record just want `result` then use this code

```
class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def result(self):
        return self.a + self.b


sum = Sum(1, 2)
print(sum.result)
sum.a = 3
print(sum.result)
```

will print

```
3
5
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found now that my code is correct. My mistake was in indentation - all property and setters were "inside" __init__ so my functions didn't working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a member called `result` and a property called `result`.  In this case, you probably do NOT want to cache the result.  You just want:

```
class Sum:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def result(self):
        return self.a + self.b

s = Sum(3,4)
s.a = 4
print(s.result)
```

will print 8.

Comment: I exectly want to store my result for further calculations. Above code is just a simple example of my problem. In real project I am working on - mortgage loan calculator. One of parametres is date of first installment and duration (in months), so I want to derive last installment date with some date math and store this value in instance's attribute.

Comment: Values that can be easily computed should not be stored in member variables.  If you do that, then they won't be recomputed when you change the input values.  Caching computed values is only a win if they are expensive to compute.